# python text file reading is slow

Tags: python, file, pattern-matching

How can I make this python program read a big text file faster? My code takes almost five minutes to read the text file, but I need it to do that much faster. I think my algorithm is not in O(n).

Some sample data (the [actual data](http://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1amEKl64LwKTUtFRzNjWTQ3Nm8) is 470K+ rows):

```
Aarika
Aaron
aaron
Aaronic
aaronic
Aaronical
Aaronite
Aaronitic
Aaron's-beard
Aaronsburg
Aaronson
```

My code:

```
import string
import re


WORDLIST_FILENAME = "words.txt"

def load_words():
 wordlist = []
 print("Loading word list from file...")
 with open(WORDLIST_FILENAME, 'r') as f:
     for line in f:
         wordlist = wordlist + str.split(line)
 print("  ", len(wordlist), "words loaded.")
 return wordlist

def find_words(uletters):
wordlist = load_words()
foundList = []

for word in wordlist:
    wordl = list(word)
    letters = list(uletters)
    count = 0
    if len(word)==7:
        for letter in wordl[:]:
            if letter in letters:
                wordl.remove(letter)
               # print("word left" + str(wordl))
                letters.remove(letter)                    
               # print(letters)
                count = count + 1
                #print(count)
                if count == 7:
                    print("Matched:" + word)
                    foundList = foundList + str.split(word)
foundList.sort()
result = ''
for items in foundList: 
      result = result + items + ','
print(result[:-1])


#Test cases
find_words("eabauea" "iveabdi")
#pattern =   "asa" " qlocved"
#print("letters to look for: "+ pattern)
#find_words(pattern)
```

Comment: Sounds like a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: If you can also explain what your program is suppose to do, it will help.

Comment: One thing... `wordlist = wordlist + str.split(line)` copies the word list per line. Do `wordlist.extend(line.strip().split())`. Or if you want to get rid of duplicates and make word lookups faster, make `wordlist` a `set` instead and do `.update`.

Comment: You have two for loops, one is doing a shallow copy each time, and removing items from two lists. plus an `in` check. Also depends on how large your file is. You have also iterated through the whole file, then again through the contents. Would be helpful to explain what you are wanting to do.

Comment: Could you please provide a "words.txt" for testing purposes?

Comment: @rlee827 im not sure how to attach a text file here. any idea?

Comment: If it is too long to include directly, you can provide a link.

Comment: @rlee827 hello, this is a link for the text file https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1amEKl64LwKTUtFRzNjWTQ3Nm8

Answer (score 0):

Read the single-column file into a list with *splitlines()*:

```
def load_words():
    with open("words.txt", 'r') as f:
        wordlist = f.read().splitlines()
    return wordlist
```

You can benchmark it with `timeit`:

```
from timeit import timeit

timeit('load_words()', setup=setup, number=3)
# Output: 0.1708553659846075 seconds
```

As for how to implement what looks like a fuzzy matching algorithm, you might try 
[fuzzywuzzy](http://chairnerd.seatgeek.com/fuzzywuzzy-fuzzy-string-matching-in-python/):

```
# pip install fuzzywuzzy[speedup]

from fuzzywuzzy import process

wordlist = load_words()
process.extract("eabauea", wordlist, limit=10)
```

Output:

```
[('-a', 90), ('A', 90), ('A.', 90), ('a', 90), ("a'", 90),
 ('a-', 90), ('a.', 90), ('AB', 90), ('Ab', 90), ('ab', 90)]
```

The results are more interesting if you filter for the longer matches:

```
results = process.extract("eabauea", wordlist, limit=100)
[x for x in results if len(x[0]) > 4]
```

Output:

```
 [('abaue', 83),
 ('Ababua', 77),
 ('Abatua', 77),
 ('Bauera', 77),
 ('baulea', 77),
 ('abattue', 71),
 ('abature', 71),
 ('ablaqueate', 71),
 ('bauleah', 71),
 ('ebauche', 71),
 ('habaera', 71),
 ('reabuse', 71),
 ('Sabaean', 71),
 ('sabaean', 71),
 ('Zabaean', 71),
 ('-acea', 68)]
```

But with 470K+ rows it does take awhile:

```
timeit('process.extract("eabauea", wordlist, limit=3)', setup=setup, number=3)
# Output: 384.97334043699084 seconds
```